# Is there any way to scroll all row in SQL after delete some rows in middle of my database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row

I'm trying to scroll all of my data base (for some action like show all constants and etc. )
every thing is fine till i deleted some rows in middle of my SQL database.
i use person id as my primary key and trying to scroll data with that key.
personId is also auto Incremental.

this is my data base before delete and i can scroll fine

```
+------------------------------+
| personId |  name  |  family  |
+------------------------------+
| 1        | name1  | family1  |
| 2        | name2  | family2  |
| 3        | name3  | family3  |
| 4        | name4  | family4  |
| 5        | name5  | family5  |
| 6        | name6  | family6  |
+------------------------------+
```

and this is my database after delete

```
+------------------------------+
| personId |  name  |  family  |
+------------------------------+
| 1        | name1  | family1  | <-- num2 is deleted
| 3        | name3  | family3  | <-- num4 is deleted
| 5        | name5  | family5  |
| 6        | name6  | family6  |
+------------------------------+
```

I'm already tried to:

```
1. use ROW_NUMBER() function in WHERE clause.
2. reset personId number and auto incremental.
3. sort data by date created in Unix-time.
```

> But the logic of them is wrong and some even not working.

This is the code to retrieve a specific row of SQL data base. Where my main problem originated (=starts).

> > Person class include personId and name and family property and there Getter and Setter method. you can see it at the end of page.

```
public static Person getRow(int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE personId = ?";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try (
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
        stmt.setInt(1, rowNumber);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {            
            Person bean = new Person(rowNumber, rs.getString("name"), 
                                  rs.getString("family"));
            return bean;
        } else {
            System.err.println("No rows were found!");
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the displayAllRows() that going to invoke getRow(int rowNumber) for 1 to end as rowNumber.

```
public static void displayAllRows() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";
    try (
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...)
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    ) {
        int rowNumber = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Person bean = getRow(++rowNumber);
            System.out.println(bean.personId + ". " + bean.name + "  " + bean.family); 
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

> > Here's the person class

```
public class Person {

    private int personId;
    private String name;
    private String family;

    public Person(int personId, String name, String family) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.name = name.trim();
        this.family = family.trim();
    }

    public Person() {}

    public int getPersonId() {return personId;}
    public void setPersonId(int personId) {this.personId = personId;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getFamily() {return family;}
    public void setFamily(String family) {this.family = family;}     
}
```

---

> I know that there is other and better way to display data. But don't forget the main question and main goal of all of this.

I expect to retrieve all of data but instead i retrieve defected data and Row not found exception message.

I expect this :

```
+-------------------------+
| Row |  name  |  family  |
+-------------------------+
| 1   | name1  | family1  |
| 2   | name3  | family3  |
| 3   | name5  | family5  |
| 4   | name6  | family6  |
+-------------------------+
```

But instead i get this :

```
+-------------------------+
| Row |  name  |  family  |
+-------------------------+
| 1   | name1  | family1  |
| 3   | name5  | family5  |
+-------------------------+
```

> > > And 2 times "Row not found" Error.

Comment: Could you plz also specify what would be there in the profiles table?

Comment: A `personId` is not a row number, so why is the `getRow()` parameter named `rowNumber`. If you believe that `personId` is a row number, then think again, it is not! It is the **unique identifier** of a particular person record, and will stay unchanged even when other persons are added and removed.

Comment: *"I'm trying to scroll all of my data base"* I'm sorry, but I don't understand "scroll" in this context. What does "scroll all of my data base" mean? Are you trying to *list* all the data in your *table*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of search i finally find my answer.

> You can use resultSet.absolute(row_number) method for this goal.
>   Write your getRow() method body like this :

```
public static Person getRow(int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";
    try (
            Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    ) {
        if (resultSet.absolute(rowNumber)) {
            return new Person(resultSet.getInt("personId"), resultSet.getString("name"), 
                       resultSet.getString("family"), resultSet.getString("nationalId"));
        } else {
            System.err.println("No row were found !");
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course  you will retrieve all of your database in this way. but it work fine for data base as big as mine (;

Answer (score 0):

The cause is here. You use rowNumber to search for personId. You should not do any assumptions about what values have rowNumber. Instead, search by personId.